# subprocess in python not excecuting command

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I have a bit of code that I am designing to take a file, perform the dos2unix command on it, then copy that file to a file called INPUT, and then run a command that boots a program. From my code the first two tasks work flawlessly, however the script doesn't seem to excecute the command line which starts the program. However when I take the command line exactly as I have it written in the script, and pass it in terminal, it works fine.

here is the code:

```
import subprocess

import os

os.chdir('/home/mike/testing/crystal')

subprocess.Popen(['dos2unix mgo_input'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)


subprocess.call(['cp mgo_input INPUT'], shell=True)


subprocess.Popen(['mpirun -np 8 Pcrystal </dev/null &> mgo_singlepoint.out &'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

it is the mpirun section of the code that seems to be getting hung up

Comment: If you set `shell=True` you should pass in a string as the command argument, not a list.

Comment: Popen() returns immediately - before the called program has a chance to finish. In particular, your script will exit before mpirun can get its work done. You could use call() for all of the commands. And BTW, if you use shell=True, the input should just be a string, not a list of strings.

Comment: fixed the list, and I changed everything to call, but still no luck.

Comment: Do you still have the & on the end?

Comment: Yes. I have also tried using os.system, which doesn't work with the mpi command either

Answer (score 0):

Popen() returns before the called program finishes execution. Using call (or check_call, which checks return codes) can be a better solution. Better yet, use python for the conversion and the copy.

I'm not sure why you are piping stdout, but I'm going to assume you don't want dos2unix or mpirun to print to the screen, so I redirect them to /dev/null.

```
import subprocess
import shutil
import os

os.chdir('/home/mike/testing/crystal')
subprocess.check_call('dos2unix mgo_input', stdout=open('/dev/null','w'), shell=True)
shutil.copy2(mgo_input, 'INPUT')
subprocess.check_call('mpirun -np 8 Pcrystal', stdout=open('mgo_singlepoint.out', 'w'), stdstderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

Comment: this yields the same result as I was getting before. It converts the file and creates the INPUT file, but then the mpirun doesn't seem to start up

Comment: moved the redirection from the shell to python. As for "doesn't seem to start up"... mpirun executed and returned 0 (assuming you removed the & from the end) or python would have raised an exception. Is there anything in mg_singlepoint.out?

Comment: Solved it, seems as though I needed to specify the path where Pcrystal was located in the script, although in terminal that is not needed. Thanks

Comment: it wasn't in /home/mike/testing/crystal? chdir should have been enough.